# classified dissertations in WWII

Tags: world-war-2

What were the most important classified doctoral dissertations in physics and/or mathematics written by grad students during WWII on *any* or *all* sides of the war (US, UK, Japan, Soviet Union, Germany, Italy, etc.), especially those that took at least 20 years or more to get published and recognized?

Comment: Do you have suggestions of any dissertations that were classified? The folks I know of (and knew several of) who got PhDs around that time generally wrote up something pretty innocuous, got passed, and went of to do the classified stuff. Or, something like Feynman's thesis which had nothing to do with classified stuff.

Comment: Even most of the [Bethe-Feynman formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe–Feynman_formula) has been leaked/declassified.

Comment: @CosmasZachos that is fine and indeed an interesting episode and thank you for that, but do you know of any *university dissertation* that was classified and *stayed* classified for a while somewhere, anywhere, and it was important?

Comment: No, if I did, I would have commented on it, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos maybe my question was not clear; it would not be the first time and has happened before

Comment: In the U.S. at least, all universities I know of do not allow a dissertation to be classified. (Dissertations can sometimes be "embargoed" but classification goes beyond an embargo.) In very rare cases, the government might unexpectedly intervene and attempt to classify part or all of someone's research, because the government judges the research to be a threat to national security. But for a dissertation to be classified "by design" does not happen in the U.S. The government might sponsor a student to do classified research, but that will be kept separate from the dissertation itself.

Comment: This question is nice but it is a tough one, many phd thesis are already hard to find even if they are not classified. This is because universities have different systems for storing them and make them available.

Comment: I seem to vaguely remember some of the grad students who worked under Seaborg during the War having their dissertations partially classified.  This site (https://stlreporter.com/tag/harry-w-fulbright/) suggests Harry Fulbrights dissertation was one such, but the site seems kind of conspiratorial and I cant track any of the citations it gives to any other source, so I hesitate to post it as an answer.

Comment: In case it helps (not WW2, not math or physics): Wernher von Braun's Ph.D. dissertation "Konstruktive, theoretische und experimentelle Beiträge zu dem Problem der Flüssigkeitsrakete" (April 16, 1934, "cum laude") was classified and remained so until 1960, if memory serves. The title translates to "Design, Theoretical and Experimental Contributions to the Problem of the Liquid-Fuel Rocket". His Ph.D. diploma gave a substitute thesis title: "Über Brennversuche" ("On combustion experiments").

Comment: @njuffa excellent example! please, put in a reply so I can accept the answer!

Comment: @hyportnex I don't feel comfortable writing an answer because I relied mostly on the background information supplied by the [auction house](https://www.bonhams.com/auctions/15425/lot/3212/) when a copy of the dissertation was auctioned off in 2007 for $33K. A good answer would require further research, and I do not have time for that at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I have one example of a dissertation that was classified during World War 2 but declassified just after the war.  The dissertation of [George T. Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_T._Reynolds) is titled ["Studies in the production, propagation, and interactions of shock waves"](https://catalog.princeton.edu/catalog/9940572913506421) and consisted of three OSRD reports.   The three reports were originally completed in 1943 and classified as "confidential".  The reports were declassified and publicly available by 1946, so the contents were only classified for a short period of time.  You can read the three reports that make up the dissertation at the Library of Congress if you want.  As to its importance, from what I know it is just a standard shock tube experiment, though that was fairly cutting edge at the time.

Comment: Thank you. What is also interesting about all this is that many patents can stay classified for a long time. But I must admit that what triggered this question was a rather mundane one: actually me learning that our local school system's superintendent, a "doketeur of edjukukashion", had her "thesis" be "classified" and thereby be removed from public view; her school's policy allows this for Ed.D. , I kid you not, and we are paying for it ~$275k/year + benefits...